# Put items in a string array?

Tags: android, arrays, string

I have a little question. I want to put some strings in an String[]. How can I do this?

I tried

```
String[] categorys;
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsdata = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String myString = jsdata.getString("id_category");
                        String namecategory = jsdata.getString("category_name");
                        System.out.println("Category name" + namecategory);
                        categorys[i] = namecategory;
                    }
```

but I get `07-28 16:40:01.719: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I don't know how to use an array of Strings. Need some help.Thanks...

Comment: It needs instantiation not initialization.

Comment: if not, String[] myString = new String[jArray.length()]; add this

Comment: I was looking for this for ages!Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate the array.

```
String[] categorys = new String[jArray.length()];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the value of an element of the array which doesn't exist (your array has no elements). You need to initialize the length of the array.